# Verify method never called or only once called using Minitest::Mock

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest

Is there any way to verify a method never called or only a number of times called using Minitest::Mock

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using  the [TracePoint](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html) class with the `:call`event.

Answer (score 17):

**Specific number of times:**
Minitest::Mock forces the developer to be explicit about message expectations, so if you expect a given method to be called `x` times, you'll need to be very literal about it.

```
my_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
x.times { my_mock.expect :some_method, :return_val }
```

**Never called:**
Philosophically, Minitest shies away from testing that something doesn't happen.  While it's not completely analogous, have a look at [this post](https://www.zenspider.com/ruby/2012/01/assert_nothing_tested.html) or google "minitest assert nothing raised".

Minitest::Mock will raise a `NoMethodError` whenever an unexpected method is called on it.  That's not exactly an assertion, but probably has the desired effect.  Still, you don't particularly need a mock to do what you're asking.  You can do the same by patching your real object instance.

```
def test_string_size_never_called
  str = "foo"
  def str.size
    raise NoMethodError, "unexpected call"
  end

  # test logic continues...
end
```

Comment: For x times, how will we verify that method is only called exactly x times not x+1 times?

Comment: Because when you call your method for the n+1-th time, you'll get a MockExpectationError.  See the following gist: https://gist.github.com/chriskottom/b9a73eaffb2c5b5b6676

Answer (score 3):

Was looking for a "proper" way to test that something isn't called in minitest and stumbled upon this question.

I ended up doing it like this:

```rb
def test_foo_isnt_called
  Foo.stub(:call, proc { raise "shouldn't happen" }) do
    subject(x, y)
  end
end
```